# Mock up Go Echo context

Tags: go, integration-testing

I'm trying to test a route handler of Go echo.

Code looks like following:

```
p := NewPoint(s.db)

// Update the deduction and exchange rate.
e := echo.New()

mapD := map[string]string{"exchange_cash": "5", "exchange_point": "7"}
mapB, _ := json.Marshal(mapD)
req := httptest.NewRequest(echo.POST, "http://localhost:1323/settings/update/exchange", bytes.NewReader(mapB))
//req := httptest.NewRequest(echo.POST, "/settings/update/exchange", bytes.NewReader(mapB))
rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
c := e.NewContext(req, rec)

u := p.UpdateDeductionRate(c)
assert.Equal(s.T(), "success", u)
```

Yet this keeps give error like "Unsupported Media Type"

For Get test, code is like

```
req := httptest.NewRequest(echo.GET, "http://localhost:1323/admin/user_points/settings/get", nil)
//req := httptest.NewRequest(echo.GET, "/admin/user_points/settings/get", nil)
rec := httptest.NewRecorder()
c := e.NewContext(req, rec)
g := p.GetRates(c)
assert.Equal(s.T(), "success", g)
```

g is nil. It looks like the hander p.UpdateDeductionRate(c echo.Context),  p.GetRates(c echo.Context) is not called at all.

I feel like the echo.Context is not constructed correctly. Anyone has idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

The problem is probably that you are passing json-encoded data without specifying the `Content-Type` header.

Add `req.Header.Set(echo.HeaderContentType, echo.MIMEApplicationJSON)` to your code, and it should work:

```
req := httptest.NewRequest(echo.GET, "http://localhost:1323/admin/user_points/settings/get", nil)
req.Header.Set(echo.HeaderContentType, echo.MIMEApplicationJSON)

rec := httptest.NewRecorder()

c := e.NewContext(req, rec)
g := p.GetRates(c)

assert.Equal(s.T(), "success", g)
```